# How do you use VBA to make a form jump to the nearest future date in Access?

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to get an MS Access database to open a form either to today's date if it's in the date field in the database, or the nearest date in the future. I tried the code [here](https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/776824-open-form-record-closest-current-date), but it doesn't work. It just highlights the date field and goes to the first record instead of the nearest one in the future.

The Date field is `WorshipDate` and the table is `wp_elements`. (I am a pastor using this table to plan Sunday Worship).

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String
Dim TheDate As Date

Set db = CurrentDb
strSQL = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM wp_elements WHERE wp_elements.WorshipDate >= Date() ORDER BY wp_elements.WorshipDate;"
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
TheDate = rst.Fields(0)
WorshipDate.SetFocus
DoCmd.FindRecord TheDate, , True, , True
Set rst = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
'DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToLast
End Sub
```

I know the SQL code I included works because I am using it in a Python script that's working quite well.

What am I missing? Or is there some other, easier way to do this?

Comment: I've never tried `DoCmd.FindRecord`, but either navigate using `DoCmd.SearchForRecord` or the recordset. But for one, I assume `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdRecordsGoToLast` clears any attempt of navigating to the correct record and navigates to the last one instead.

Comment: So essentially, today's date if it exists or tomorrow's date (which is the nearest date in future)? Also, by going to tomorrow, you will attempt to launch a *new* data entry?

Comment: @Parfait I hadn't considered launching a new data entry if it did not exist, but that's a great idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only require one line of code:

```
me.RecordSet.FindFirst "Date() >= WorshipDate"
```

Comment: Should be "me.RecordSet.FindFirst "Date() <= WorshipDate".

Apart from that THIS IS IT.

Comment: Very good. I'll leave it un-corrected with your comments. Either way, this should only add and require one line of code here.